# Computed Column in Select Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, sql-server-2016

I Want To Create A %Share Column Whose Values Are Derived By Dividing The Sale Of Each Customer With The Total Sale. I'm Using The Below Query But Get Error That Column 'Sale' Cannot Be Found. Is there Is A Way Through Which I Can Get Total Of Sale Column i.e. 600 ? Please Help ...

```
Select IsNull([Customer].[FirstName],'Total') as Customer, 
        format(Sum([MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[TotalAmount]),'0.00')  [Sale],
        FORMAT(sum([MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[TotalAmount])/ sum([Sale]),'0.00%') as 'Share%'
From Customer
INNER JOIN [MY_DB].[dbo].[Order]
ON [Customer].[Id]=[MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[CustomerId]
Group By [Customer].[FirstName] with Rollup
Having (Sum([MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[TotalAmount]) > (Select AVG([MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[TotalAmount]) From [MY_DB].[dbo].[Order]))
Order By [Customer].[FirstName] Desc;
```

-

```
Desired Result: 

Customer Sale %Share
Zbyszek  100  16.66 %
Yvonne   200  33.33 %
Yoshi    300  50.00 %
```

Comment: please tag your dbms and the version if applicable.

Comment: i'm Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Comment: can you explain the reason behind using the `having` condition? your query shows it,but the expected result doesn't.

Comment: by using the having condition i'm trying to filter customers whose sale is greater then the avg. sale i.e. 200. in that case only one record will remain-Yoshi 300 50.00%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the existing query quite a bit. I don't think you need `with rollup`.

For getting the total sales use `sum() over()`. Then divide each sale amount by the total to get the percentage. In the same way, using `avg() over()` you can compute the average and find customers with sales >= avgamount.

```
Select Customer,[Sale],[Share%]
from (
Select Distinct 
c.[FirstName] as Customer, 
format(sum(o.[TotalAmount]) over(partition by o.[CustomerId]),'0.00') as [Sale],
format(100.0*sum(o.[TotalAmount]) over(partition by o.[CustomerId]) / sum(o.[TotalAmount]) over(),'0.00%') as 'Share%',
AVG(o.[TotalAmount]) over() as 'AvgAmount'
From Customer c
INNER JOIN [MY_DB].[dbo].[Order] o ON c.[Id]=o.[CustomerId]
) t 
Where Sale >= AvgAmount
Order By Customer Desc;
```

Without computing the average you can just check for customers with share >= 50%.

```
Select Customer,[Sale],[Share%]
from (
Select Distinct 
c.[FirstName] as Customer, 
format(sum(o.[TotalAmount]) over(partition by o.[CustomerId]),'0.00') as [Sale],
format(100.0*sum(o.[TotalAmount]) over(partition by o.[CustomerId]) / sum(o.[TotalAmount]) over(),'0.00%') as 'Share%'
From Customer c
INNER JOIN [MY_DB].[dbo].[Order] o ON c.[Id]=o.[CustomerId]
) t 
Where [Share%] >= 50
Order By Customer Desc;
```

Comment: gives error:Column 'MY_DB.dbo.Order.CustomerId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: if possible can you please explain how 'partition by' works in this scenario?

Comment: `partition by` is similar to `group by` in window functions. because you need the total sales per customer you partition by customer. To get the total sum you have to look at all rows and hence `sum(totalamount) over()`, without a partition specification. read more about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define [Sale] column and use it in a function in the same SQL.
Easiest way to achieve this is just to surround your SQL with an outer SQL statement, where you'll also calculate the total sum and make the division.

(My syntax might not be MS-SQL exact, but this is to illustrate the idea)

```
Select [data].[FirstName], 
      format([data].[Sale],'0.00'), 
      format([data].[Sale] / [total].[totalSum],'0.00') FROM

(Select IsNull([Customer].[FirstName],'Total') as Customer, 
       Sum([MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[TotalAmount]  [Sale],
       From Customer
       INNER JOIN [MY_DB].[dbo].[Order]
       ON [Customer].[Id]=[MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[CustomerId]
       Group By [Customer].[FirstName] with Rollup
       Having (Sum([MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[TotalAmount]) > (Select AVG([MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[TotalAmount]) From [MY_DB].[dbo].[Order])) ) data, 
(Select sum([MY_DB].[dbo].[Order].[TotalAmount] as [totalSum]) from [MY_DB].[dbo].[Order]) total
Order By [data].[FirstName] Desc;
```